# Motherboard activates on mains power on

Tags: motherboard

I have Openmediavault running on the following configuration:

1. [ASRock J4105-ITX](https://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/J4105-ITX/) Motherboard (it has this Intel J4105 processor soldered onto the motherboard, passive CPU cooler)
2. Antec BP450P PSU, Crucial 4GB DDR4 RAM, Seagate Barracuda HDD for file shares, Kingston A400 SSD for OS

Whenever I switch the mains on (switch on the UPS), the system becomes active momentarily even before I press the ATX power button. The power and HDD LEDs light up, I hear a motor spinning up which I believe is the HDD. The only fan in the system, the PSU fan, is very quiet though it does spin too. And then, 5-6 seconds later, all goes back to quiet, LEDs turn off and the motor spins down. There is no beep from the onboard system speaker.

All this while, pressing the ATX power button doesn't start the system. Only after the system becomes quite again does the ATX button start the system, gives a POST beep, and the system continues to run without any issue thereafter.
I am worried this unwanted spin-up might hurt the HDD. (Recently a new HDD failed all of a sudden on this system. Although I can't rule out the possibility of the HDD being defective from the factory).

Is this normal? Does it affect the HDD or any other peripheral?
I have not made any changes to the UEFI settings except for choosing the boot disk and enabling WOL. I read the [motherboard manual](https://download.asrock.com/Manual/J4105-ITX.pdf), searched through the UEFI settings as well as on the internet, but couldn't find any relevant information. It seems either I am the only one worried about it or I am the only one having this problem.

Any guidance would be really helpful.
Thank you.

Comment: Some main boards have a 'last state' setting for power, so if it was off it stays off when power is restored, and when it was on it turns itself back on. Perhaps your main board has this functionality? Not sure why it wouldn't continue booting afterward though, that's the strange part.

Comment: @MIG That UEFI has that setting. See the answer I just posted while you typed your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Check the status of the UEFI setting 'Restore on AC/Power loss'.
Make sure this is set to OFF.

That may fix the problem.

If it doesn't you will have to live with it. I don't think you have to worry about premature wear because of this.

Comment: Thanks Tonny, MiG. This setting is already set to off. I should have mentioned that in the question. I believe I have to let it be and hope for the best.